# Asterisk Video Playback (mp4/3gp)

Tags: video, asterisk, mp4, 3gp, agi

I'm trying to play a video file during a call with asterisk 1.4 for a couple of days now without success.
**I'm able** to make video calls to other users using codec h263 and h264 but **I'm not able to play my own mp4 or 3gp files**.
Whenever I chose these type of files asterisk simply stops executing without any debug information that I can use (verbose is at 6)

**The videos files that I have have these specs:**

```
[root@myserver ~]# mp4info /meus/asterisk_videos/sample_mpeg4.mp4
mp4info version 1.5.0.1
/meus/asterisk_videos/sample_mpeg4.mp4:
Track   Type    Info
1       audio   MPEG-4 AAC LC, 4.992 secs, 48 kbps, 32000 Hz
2       video   MPEG-4 Adv Simple@L3, 4.966 secs, 512 kbps, 190x240 @ 30.004027 fps


[root@myserver ~]# mp4info /meus/asterisk_videos/sample.3gp
mp4info version 1.5.0.1
/meus/asterisk_videos/sample.3gp:
Track   Type    Info
1       audio   AMR, 5.000 secs, 8 kbps, 8000 Hz
2       video   MPEG-4 Simple @ L0, 4.933 secs, 40 kbps, 176x144 @ 15.001014 fps
```

**The following AGI playback command plays all audio files but not video:**

```
$agi->exec("Playback", "/meus/asterisk_videos/sample_mpeg4");
$agi->exec("Playback", "/meus/asterisk_videos/sample");
```

**rasterisk AGI DEBUG shows:**

```
AGI Rx << ANSWER
AGI Tx >> 200 result=0
AGI Rx << EXEC Playback /meus/asterisk_videos/sample
    -- AGI Script Executing Application: (Playback) Options: (/meus/asterisk_videos/sample)
AGI Tx >> 200 result=0
AGI Rx << HANGUP
AGI Tx >> 200 result=1
```

**Do you know the exact specs that a 3gp or mp4 file needs in order to play under asterisk ?**
Any tips, links or suggestions will be very welcome. **Thank you all!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the mp4play application for the asterisk. This application is not directly included in the asterisk. I had tested and run it for asterisk 1.4.32 or similar.

you can get the application related info here www.medooze.com/products/asterisk-applications/app_mp4.aspx

and you can download from svn here http://asteriskvideo.svn.sourceforge.net/
you can get the download instructions at http://web.archive.org/web/20090322060930/http://sip.fontventa.com/content/view/15/44/

try googling and see the mailing list for asterisk video. You will get  more resources.

Comment: nice catch the web-archive ;-) I was searching for the asterisk mp4 app docs but I couldn't found it... thanks! 1+